# Better way to Migrate user profiles

Tags: migration

Currently I am copying over their files by moving their user dir from one machine to the other. Then I create the account.

Is that the correct and best way to go? I am moving machines from 10.7 to 10.9. I would ike to also move all their application settings and more if possible.

I am a Windows/Linux guy.

Answer (score 1):

/Applications/Utilities/Migration Assistant.app That is the recommended way from Apple. It grabs the necessary information and allows the user to work just as before. Easy peasy